# run a cumsum total inside a loop

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a sequential grouped table in Pandas.

I am trying to create a running sum within groups, conditional upon running sum can not be negative
using the loop below I am able to create the same
As you can see for the user_id 77558 the subtotal continues from user_id 223
how do I Fix this

```
user_id = [4705,4705,4705,4705,4705,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,77558,77558,77558,77558,77558,77558,77558,77558,77558,77558]
transaction_c= [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Credit_Debit = [75,-125,47,75,-122,50,50,100,-200,35,50,-15,100,27,27,-54,1000,-220,-220,-220,-220,1000,]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(user_id,transaction_c,Credit_Debit)), columns =['user_id','transaction', 'Credit_Debit'])

#summary function 

lastvalue = 0
newtotal = []
for row in df['Credit_Debit']:
    thisvalue =  row + lastvalue
    if thisvalue < 0:
        thisvalue = 0
    newtotal.append( thisvalue )
    lastvalue = thisvalue
    
df['Balance']=pd.Series(newtotal, index=df.index)
```

output

```
+---------+-------------+--------------+----------+------------------+
| user_id | transaction | Credit_Debit | Balance  | Desired Balance  |
+---------+-------------+--------------+----------+------------------+
|    4705 |           1 |           75 |       75 |               75 |
|    4705 |           2 |         -125 |        0 |                0 |
|    4705 |           3 |           47 |       47 |               47 |
|    4705 |           4 |           75 |      122 |              122 |
|    4705 |           5 |         -122 |        0 |                0 |
|     223 |           1 |           50 |       50 |               50 |
|     223 |           2 |           50 |      100 |              100 |
|     223 |           3 |          100 |      200 |              200 |
|     223 |           4 |         -200 |        0 |                0 |
|     223 |           5 |           35 |       35 |               35 |
|     223 |           6 |           50 |       85 |               85 |
|     223 |           7 |          -15 |       70 |               70 |
|   77558 |           1 |          100 |      170 |              100 |
|   77558 |           2 |           27 |      197 |              127 |
|   77558 |           3 |           27 |      224 |              154 |
|   77558 |           4 |          -54 |      170 |              100 |
|   77558 |           5 |         1000 |     1170 |             1100 |
|   77558 |           6 |         -220 |      950 |              880 |
|   77558 |           7 |         -220 |      730 |              660 |
|   77558 |           8 |         -220 |      510 |              440 |
|   77558 |           9 |         -220 |      290 |              220 |
|   77558 |          10 |         1000 |     1290 |             1220 |
+---------+-------------+--------------+----------+------------------+
```

Appreciate all the help in doing resolving this .
thanks :)

Comment: df.loc[df['Total_Balance']<0,'Total_Balance']=0
?

Comment: if I do that, that would not take the cumulative total ahead, for example in  line number 3 the total balance would go to 0 but what should come up there is 47

Comment: The linked dup is for upper threshold, but can be easily modified to fit lower threshold (0).